# Let the web page run on web server?

Tags: node.js, bryntum-scheduler

I was using Bryntum Scheduler, but can't import it because of CORS policy.
After my research, I got to know that creating a web server can solve that.

So I have learned some node.js and create a web server.

Then it's the question.
I created a web server, but how can I run my page on it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to serve static assets in order to serve a web page.

This is perfectly doable using pure NodeJS but if you just want to get going, take a look at the Express framework and “Express generator” that lets you scaffold a web server very quickly.

https://expressjs.com
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html